# VS code Pygame not loading mp3 music

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame, mp3

I have the following code which works fine in Python IDle, but when running it in VS code I can't get it to play the mp3 file:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('Sound.mp3')
mixer.music.play(-1)
```

it throws this error message:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.7.1)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ilopezdeveloper/start.py", line 9, in <module>
    mixer.music.load('Sound.mp3')
pygame.error: Couldn't open 'Sound.mp3'
```

I've done some research but couldn't find any information which could explain what's going wrong. What is most strange is that if I open the file with Python IDlE I can hear the sound.mp3 file playing with no problem.
Does anyone know what the problem is? Thank you.

Comment: Since your filename is relative I would check if the working directory of the script is the same in IDLE and in VSCode.

Comment: Thank you Niko B! It's exactly that. IDle uses by default the current file directory as the working directory. But VS Code uses the workspace directory as the working directory. And if you don't have a workspace open, VS code uses by default users/your_user_name as the current directory. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

As @[Niko B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7033655/niko-b) explained in the above comment, and just so an answer to this question can be used by other people, the problem had to do with the Working directory. IDlE's default working directory is the directory where the running file is. For VS code the default working directory is the workspace folder. If there is no workspace open, it takes c:\users\your_user_name as the working directory.

**Solution**: change the working directory to the folder where the file you want to run is. Either by setting a workspace to that folder or setting the 'terminal.integrated.cwd' in JSON to that directory.

Comment: Settings--> Python>Terminal>Execute In File Dir 
Will change the working directory to the file directory when running Python files.